# What design pattern is suitable for my scenario

Tags: java, oop

I have two classes - class A and B.

class A receives a message from upper layer, and I want to forward this message to class B to process. When B processes this message, it will update its own state and generates a few events. There is an method in class A which can send these events to upper layer.

I cannot change sendEventToUpperLayer() in class A. So how can I return the generated events in class B and its state back to class A? Should I simply discard class B, and move class B's logic into class A?

```
public class A {
    private B b;
    private void processMessage(Message) {
        b.processMessage(Message);
    }

    private void sendEventToUpperLayer() {
    }
}

public class B {
    public void processMessage(Message) {
        // It will generate a few events and update b's state.
        // All these events and b's state will need to use class A's method of sendEventToUpperLayer() to forward to upper layer.
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly is not clear what you are trying to do. I could hazard a suggestion, have a look at [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: Thanks freedev. Actually Observer Pattern is the first pattern coming into my mind. But observer pattern only involves observable notifying observer. In my case, I consider my class A as observable and class B as observer since class A will notify class B by using b.processMessage(Message). But my question is how can class B use class A's method, which is inverse notifying?

Comment: You could also try with delegation, passing to the contained `B` a lambda, a method or an object useful to callback the container `A`.

Comment: Thanks freedev, actually I might callback the container A for a few times, since there will be a few events generated when class B processed the message. So I am thinking to pass class A's instance to class B's instance by using b.process(Message, class A' instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `class A` implement an interface for sending messages, one that declares sendEventToUpperLayer or a more genericly named version of such (which your implementation then delegates to the existing sendEventToUpperLayer method).

Then pass `class A` to `class B`'s `processMessage` method as a parameter, which class B accepts as the named interface (not directly as class A).

Class B can then call the necessary method of class A as many times as necessary, and since it is an interface does not need class A directly and can be unit tested appropriately etc.

If appropriate, you can also pass class A (via an interface as mentioned previously) to class B in class B's constructor, if the class B instance will always be referring to the same class A instance for its callbacks.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Your suggested way is much better than what I thought about passing class A's instance. Actually, I am also thinking about a second solution to discard class B and move class B's logic into class A. So how do you suggest pros/cons for both solutions?

Comment: @Lazysheep.wang Depends on how coupled the classes are.  If class B will never exist outside of having a class A, then you could combine their logic, or implement class B as an inner class of class A.  Generally speaking though, it often feels cleaner if you split the logic into separate classes appropriately, even if you have to pass class A to class B.  Really depends on the details of the particular case (e.g. does class B have data / state or is it only methods, etc).